# Make clean error

Tags: linux, makefile, shared-libraries

I am experimenting with custom libraries and while going through the steps of adding one I cannot seem to get past a make file error. I researched it a bit online and found that we need to use tabs instead of whitespaces and likewise change the content. I have also tried editing it in vi instead of gedit. I have also gone through a couple of other solutions and guides regarding make errors related to this but to no avail.I am posting the file in this thread. Could someone please let me know what the problem is? Executing the command "make clean" is generating the following error:

```
Makefile:687: *** missing separator. Stop.
```

Makefile.am

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = 1.4 foreign
CFLAGS += -Wall
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libopen.la
libopen_la_SOURCES = libopen.c
libopen_la_CFLAGS = -O1
libopen_la_LIBADD = -ldl
dist_man_MANS = libopen.1

edit = $(SED) \
    -e 's,@bindir\@,$(bindir),g' \
    -e 's,@mandir\@,$(mandir),g' \
    -e 's,@libdir\@,$(libdir),g' \
    -e 's,@datadir\@,$(datadir),g' \
    -e 's,@localstatedir\@,$(localstatedir),g'


openlib:: Makefile $(srcdir)/openlib.in
    rm -f openlib openlib.tmp && \
    $(edit) $(srcdir)/openlib.in >openlib.tmp \
    && mv openlib.tmp openlib

nodist_bin_SCRIPTS = openlib
nodist_bin_SCRIPTS += openlib-debug

dist_noinst_DATA = openlib.in
dist_noinst_DATA += openlib-debug.in

DISTCLEANFILES = openlib
DISTCLEANFILES += openlib-debug
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the contents of `Makefile` around line 687? Are the leading spaces on those `openlib` rule lines tabs?

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you escaping the second `@` in those `sed` commands?

Comment: Go look at the `Makefile` and show us the content at (and a few lines before and after) line 687.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that you have some extra spaces after one of your backslashes.  The backslash must be the last thing on the line before the newline, or it doesn't count as escaping the newline.  If you look at line 687, and the line right before it, you'll be able to see where the problem is.

Comment: @Etan Reisner,I was merely following the code in the guide given to me.

Comment: @Guys, Thanks for the valuable suggestions. Apparently, the problem was due to the lack of tabs in the mentioned line in the make file, It worked like a charm as soon as I added them. I guess I was looking in the wrong file.